# Comparing Function Pointers in Stream Class

Tags: c++, stream, function-pointers

I'm trying to write my own stream class. It will do something with the input and pass it on to `std::cout`. So far I passed functions operating on the stream (e.g. `std::endl`) on to `cout`. Now, I want to check for `std::endl` input and perform some actions, if it occurs. I have implemented the behaviour like this

```
DebugStream& DebugStream::operator<< (ostream& (*pfun)(ostream&))
{
  if(pfun == std::endl)
  {
    // do something
  }

  pfun(cout);
  return *this;
}
```

Which results into

```
/path/to/file.cpp:89:24: error: assuming cast to type ‘std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)’ from overloaded function [-fpermissive]
```

using the GCC compiler. I don't know, how to compare the function pointer against the `std::endl` function. Maybe this problem is related to the template nature of the `std::endl` function? Or because it's inline?

Comment: Maybe you should be writing your own [stream buffer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) instead and do something special when `\n` is printed. `std::endl` just prints `\n` and flushes; as a user of your class, I could do these steps by hand and skip your `if` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a warning is that `std::endl` is a template function. You can fix this error by forcing a comparison to a template instance of a particular type through a cast, like this:

```
typedef ostream& (*io_manip_ptr_t)(ostream&);

void demo(io_manip_ptr_t pfun) {
    if (pfun == (io_manip_ptr_t)&endl) {
        cout << "Hi" << endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/NdRFiQ)

**Note:** Even though the work-around is available, this is only a workaround, not a solid solution, because comparing function pointers to decide on functionality introduces a very serious problem: your functions get reduced to an `enum`, so your code becomes impossible to extend from the outside.